# Fluid simulation wrong behavior

Tags: fluid-simulation

The fluid seems to explode in the first frame and then back to normal. This is the first time it happened.

I applied the scale for both the domain and the flow object!
[image: see this]

[image]

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x5ekuRz7fYd3rNXIW67QpANntlGwvm4y/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: maybe you could try to move the inflow completely in your domain - if this doesn't help please provide blend file

Comment: Or try to change resolution and restart animation, this water is sus (sorry I had to)

Comment: it is completely in the domain here is the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AV-1fLLJcOXTWbNpRKAf01dCXGrx7yEd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i was trying to follow this tutorial I'm not sure how it works with him! youtu.be/vkqgFIUmAPU

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is *Liquid >* **Diffusion** setup ... I'm not a math guy, but from presets it looks like *Base* shouldn't be bigger than *Exponent*. If you disable *Diffusion* feature or if you use some of the given presets it works fine.

For more info see [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/physics/fluid/type/domain/liquid/diffusion.html)

Your setup
Frame 3 with Diffusion > **Base 6, Exponent 1**

[image]

Preset > Honey
Frame 3 with Diffusion > **Base 2, Exponent 3**

[image]

Lowres 64
[image]

Comment: i was trying to follow this tutorial I'm not sure how it works with him!  https://youtu.be/vkqgFIUmAPU